# Summing results by month in SAS

Tags: sas

I have this kind of data

```
Configuration   Retail Price    month
 1               450         Jan
 1               520         Feb
 1               630         Mar
 5               650         Jan
 5               320         Feb
 5               480         Mar
 9               770         Jan
 9               180         Feb
 9               320         Mar
```

I want my data to look like this

```
Configuration   Jan Feb Mar
      1         450 520 630
      5         650 320 480
      9         770 180 320
```

Comment: Please show your attempt at a solution, and explain where you are stuck. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: You don't appear to be summing the data at all.  Use `proc transpose`  to transpose data.

Answer (score 0):

Generating some data to tinker with:

```
data begin;
    length Configuration 3  Retail_Price 3 month $3;
    input Configuration  Retail_Price month;
    datalines;
     1 450 Jan
     1 520 Feb
     1 630  Mar
     5 650 Jan
     5 320 Feb
     5 480 Mar
     9 770 Jan
     9 180 Feb
     9 320 Mar
     ; 
run;
```

In SAS everything must be sorted right. (Or you can use index, but that different thing) We use **PROC SORT** for this.

```
proc sort data= begin; by Configuration month; run;
```

A way to calculate sum is to utilize **PROC MEANS**.

```
proc means data=begin noprint; /*Noprint is for convienience*/
    by Configuration month; /*These are the subsets*/
    output out = From_means(drop=_TYPE_ _FREQ_) /*Drops are for ease sake*/
    sum(Retail_Price)=
    ;
run;
```

At this point we have the data in narrow format. A way to transform this to wide format is **PROC TRANSPOSE**.

```
proc transpose data=From_means out=Wide_format;
    by Configuration;
    id month;
run;
```

Bear in mind that there are multiple other ways to accomplish the same. A popular way is to utilize **PROC SQL** for almost everything, but in my experience large datasets are better to be handled by SAS proc commands..